# Study the stability of the following system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Study the stability of the system $x'=Ax+b(t)$ where $$A=\left(\begin{array}{rcl}
c & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 5\\
0 & -5 & 1 \end{array} \right)$$
Is there an easy way to solve this problem? Or a general method to approach? Thanks!...

Comment: What does "stability" mean in this context?  What would "studying the stability" usually entail?

Comment: Yes you right. In the Lyapunov sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "studying the stability", but the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of this matrix are easy to find.

Namely, we have the eigenvectors $c,1 + 5i,1-5i$, with respective eigenvectors
$$
\pmatrix{1\\0\\0},\pmatrix{0\\-i\\1},\pmatrix{0\\i\\1}
$$

---

Assuming your question is consistent with others you've asked, it seems that the system is never stable, since there will always be an eigenvalue with a positive real part.